# When making a string into a url it goes to nil

Tags: ios, json, swift, url

I an using Swift with an API to get a JSON

I have tested It with the function I am trying to get it to work with and it doesn't work but when I use print statements it is like this:

```
let url = 
"""
https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeathsByDeathDate":"newDeathsByDeathDate","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"cumDeathsByDeathDate"}}
"""
print(url)
print(URL(string: url))
```

And the output is:

```
https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=nation;areaName=england&structure={"date":"date","areaName":"areaName","areaCode":"areaCode","newCasesByPublishDate":"newCasesByPublishDate","cumCasesByPublishDate":"cumCasesByPublishDate","newDeathsByDeathDate":"newDeathsByDeathDate","cumDeathsByDeathDate":"cumDeathsByDeathDate"}}
nil
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Your URL is simply broken

Comment: Yeah, try putting the url in your web browser. You've got a typo somewhere

Comment: Use `URLComponents` to construct your URL

Comment: Pasting that URL into a browser gives "{"response":"Invalid structure. The structure must either be a JSON, or an Array object. Make sure you use double quotation marks in the structure.","status_code":417,"status":"Expectation Failed"}".  Putting the `structure` into JSONLint.com shows one too many } at the end, but even removing that results in rejection.  You should probably use `POST` rather than `GET` with such a complex input requirement.  Also I think the values in the structure should be filter strings, not just the key again

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end

Comment: url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)